# How do I compute the 16-bit sum of the 8-bit values of an array in assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, arduino, sum, avr

Feel like I've been asking a lot of these questions lately lol, but assembly is still pretty foreign to me.

Using an Arduino, I have to write a function in Atmel AVR Assembly for my computer science class that calculates the sum of the 8-bit values in an array and returns it as a 16-bit integer. The function is supposed to take in an array of bytes and a byte representing the length of the array as arguments, with those arguments stored in r24 and r22, respectively, when the function is called. I am allowed to use branching instructions and such.

The code is in this format:

```
.global sumArray
sumArray:
  //magic happens
  ret
```

I know how to make loops and increment the counter and things like that, but I am really lost as to how I would do this.

I am unsure as to how I would do this. Does anyone know how to write this function in Atmel AVR Assembly? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: use `ADD` and `ADC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you ask the question to your compiler?

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t sumArray(uint8_t *val, uint8_t count)
{
    uint16_t sum = 0;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        sum += val[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Compiling with `avr-gcc -std=c99 -mmcu=avr5 -Os -S sum8-16.c` generates
the following assembly:

```
.global sumArray
sumArray:
    mov  r19, r24
    movw r30, r24
    ldi  r24, 0
    ldi  r25, 0
.L2:
    mov  r18, r30
    sub  r18, r19
    cp   r18, r22
    brsh .L5
    ld   r18, Z+
    add  r24, r18
    adc  r25,__zero_reg__
    rjmp .L2
.L5:
    ret
```

This may not be the most straight-forward solution, but if you study
this code, you can understand how it works and, hopefully, come with
your own version.

Comment: Ahh ok thank you, I had been trying out godbolt.org before, this solution is much clearer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Didn't know about this site, thanks for the link! The code it generates is not a whole more complex than the one above (15 instructions v.s. 13), provided you give it the options `-mmcu=avr5 -Os`.

Answer (score 0):

Iif you want something quick and dirty, add the two 8-bit values into an 8-bit register. If the sum is less than the inputs, then make a second 8-bit register equal to 1, otherwise 0. That's how you can do the carry.

The processor should already have something called a carry flag that you can use to this end.

Answer (score 0):

with pencil and paper how do I add two two digit decimal numbers when I was only taught to add two single digit numbers at a time?   12 + 49?   I can add the 2+9 = 11 then what do I do?  (search for the word carry)